# What's wrong with my NSRegularExpression?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios6, nsregularexpression

```
    NSString *body = @"...";

    // Remove all HTML and formatting from body
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"(&lt;.*?&gt;|\\n|\\t|&.*?;)" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&error];
    body = [regex stringByReplacingMatchesInString:body options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [body length]) withTemplate:@""];
```

But when I compile it, I get this error:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSRegularExpression
>   enumerateMatchesInString:options:range:usingBlock:]: nil argument'

I tested the pattern in a regular expression editor and it works, I don't see what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: Is that the exact code used in your program? I'm running it and not getting any errors.

Comment: Are you sure body isn't nil in your actual code?

Comment: This happens to me too, but I'm only seeing it with Crashlytics in my live application. I haven't been able to send a string which causes the crash in my testing. Quite the head scratcher.